# j2me sample location based code and advice

Tags: java-me, mobile, location

I need your help with resources or advice for creating a j2me location based application. I need a complete  sample code that actually works on netbeans, it needs to be very simple, just showing basic latitude and longitude. If any of you can give me any advice, I will be greatful as I am still a bit lost on this. Thank you guys, any advice or code will be of much help . Thank you. :-)

Comment: I developed an application for sending sms, works on netbeans and on my phone. I tried to play with some codes I researched on internet for lbs, but I can't find a code that actually compiles on netbeans and the pieces of code I find, I don't know where I should fit them in my sms application, or if I should create another class, I also get the message: myClass is public and should be put in a file named myClass.java, but I don't know how to actually put the file in the correct place, I created a midlet... Very confusing and I didn't want to fail the module. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you had look at these Nokia resources ?
[Google Maps API in Java ME](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Google_Maps_API_in_Java_ME) and [How to get Location Using Location API JSR 179](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_get_Location_Using_Location_API_JSR_179)

Comment: I looked and tried to put the code on netbeans, but it says class or interface expected. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to tell us which code you did try, what WTK you are using.